# Poincare duality for algebraic de Rham cohomology with integrable connection coefficients

Tags: algebraic-curves, connections, de-rham-cohomology, poincare-duality

I am reading "The Gauss-Manin Connection and Tannaka Duality" ([here](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/esnault/preprints/helene/78-gauss-manin.pdf) is the link to the paper). I am specifically interested in the proof of Proposition 2.2. In this proof, the authors use the Poincaré duality for algebraic de Rham cohomology of a smooth projective curve $X$ over a field $K$ of characteristic $0$ with integrable connection coefficient $(\mathcal V,\bigtriangledown)$. You can see this line lies between equations (2.12) and (2.13) in the paper:

> $H^2_{dR}(X,(\mathcal V, \bigtriangledown)) $ is a Poincaré dual to $H^0_{dR}(X,(\mathcal V,\bigtriangledown)^\vee)$, where $(\mathcal V, \bigtriangledown)^\vee$ is the dual connection.

However, I can not find any references for proof of this claim. In *the Stacks project* ([here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FW7)), this duality is only proven for trivial connections $(\Omega ^ p_{X/k},d)$. So I wonder whether any of you have a reference for this more general duality.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have seen Proposition $2.5$, page$7$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1182.pdf), where Esnault summarises duality results ("reminders on duality"). I don't know if it applies. Perhaps there are other reminders in some of her papers.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde
The duality you mention is for etale cohomology. I have searched more in her other papers but it seems that she did not mention it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It appears in the book "De Rham Cohomology of Differential Modules on Algebraic Varieties" of Yves André, Francesco Baldassarri, and Maurizio Cailotto, Theorem D.2.17.